# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot, asks for low graphics mode, can't run apt-get because file system is read-only

Tags: ubuntu, boot

My computer won't boot anymore I think because it ran out of disk space.  It asks to boot in low graphics mode and then gets stuck checking battery state.  When I boot in recovery mode I run clean and it says it's okay and gets stuck.  I go to root terminal and try to delete things or run `apt-get` and I can't because I can't delete the lock file or anything else.  Any ideas?

Comment: First boot a live CD and run `fsck`.

Comment: Run `df -k` to check for full disks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if the Linux OS changes a mount to RO, then there is some type of driver or serious structural error in the filesystem has happened.  Please before you possibly damage the disk further, do a FULL fsck on the disk.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Let fsck have a crack at repairing it.  If you have a state in which the file system is mounted read-only, you should immediately backup everything you might need should a reformat and reinstall be required.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution which worked for me:

1) press  <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>

2) login whith your credentials

3) enter `sudo pkill X`

X server will restart and login screen will come up..

Answer (score 0):

Get into recovery mode and type

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

You should have your read-write mode set

Comment: I wouldn't remount the filesystem rw until you're sure it isn't corrupt.  Doing this on a bad filesystem is probably going to make things worse.